# How do I provide a default implementation in a child interface?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

If I have an interface `IExampleInterface`:

```
interface IExampleInterface {
    int GetValue();
}
```

Is there a way to provide a default implementation for `GetValue()` in a child interface? I.e.:

```
interface IExampleInterfaceChild : IExampleInterface {
    // Compiler warns that we're just name hiding here. 
    // Attempting to use 'override' keyword results in compiler error.
    int GetValue() => 123; 
}
```

Comment: Interfaces do not contain any code.

Comment: @TaW they do in the newest version of c#. many think that was a bad design choice, but that's a matter of opinion. @Xenoprimate did you try `new int GetValue() => 123;`?

Comment: Hm, interesting, although quite counter-intuitive. But things tend to grow on one.. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more experimentation, I found the following solution:

```
interface IExampleInterfaceChild : IExampleInterface {
    int IExampleInterface.GetValue() => 123; 
}
```

Using the name of the interface whose method it is that you're providing an implementation for is the right answer (i.e. `IParentInterface.ParentMethodName() => ...`).

I tested the runtime result using the following code:

```
class ExampleClass : IExampleInterfaceChild {
        
}

class Program {
    static void Main() {
        IExampleInterface e = new ExampleClass();

        Console.WriteLine(e.GetValue()); // Prints '123'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# 8.0+ the interfaces can have a default method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#default-interface-methods

Otherwise if you are using lower version on C# due to using .Net Framework, you may use an abstract class. but If you want your classes to be able to implement several interfaces, this option may not work for you:

```
public abstract class ExampleInterfaceChild : IExampleInterface {
    int GetValue() => 123; 
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is asking how/if it is possible to provide a default implementation in an interface for an interface member in the parent interface.

Comment: @Xenoprimate yes, the link to the documentation is the answer.